# How to Merge Model with Relationship

Tags: laravel

Please help, I try to merge Model and Relathionship data.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function rank()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\rank','id','id');
    }
}
```

in my controller

```
User::with('rank')->first();
```

current result : [user:['username':'gugu',rank:['rank':3]]]

what i expect : [user:['username':'gugu',rank:3]]

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators

Comment: try User::with('rank')->all()->first();

Answer (score 0):

Alright, relations return collection or an item depending on type of the relation.

What you have to do is to write a accessor

```
public function getRankAttribute() {
    return $this->rank->rank;
}
```

And then you access rank like this

```
$user->rank
```

Comment: thanks for your respond @jagadesha, i have try to write accessor in my User model but still the same result.

Comment: ok, i understand how to use. but i need pass my data to vue component with merged array @jagadeshanh.  actually i can merge manually if only a single data, but in my case i have alot of nested users in tree. so i try to find a solution to merge it.